# changing values in a file

Tags: c, file

A file created with data as

- id    name  quantity   cost
- 1     book   23         456
- 2     pen    42         23
- 3     toy    76         28

---

in this how can I change values(cost) with respect to amount of quantity selected after each edit on files

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

struct inventory
{
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int qty;
    double price;
} i[50];

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int j,n;

    clrscr();
    printf("\n Enter number of recorrds");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    fp=fopen("inven.txt","a");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("\n File cannot open");
    }

    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter spare part id");
        scanf("%d",&i[j].id);
        printf("\n Enter name");
        scanf("%s",i[j].name);
        printf("\n Enter quantity");
        scanf("%d",&i[j].qty);
        printf("\n Enter price");
        scanf("%lf",&i[j].price);
        fprintf(fp,"\n %d\t%s\t%d\t%lf",i[j].id,i[j].name,i[j].qty,i[j].price);
    }
}

void dummy()
{
    float *f1,f;
    f1=&f;
}
```

Comment: Oh horrible! Go format your code before I even want to look at it!

Comment: Are you trying to write a file once with the correct values, or edit the file later after the values change?

Comment: i want to edit file later

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes in the file you shouldn't use the append mode of `fopen`.

`"r"` - Opens a file for reading. The file must exist.

`"w"` - Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already 
exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file.

`"a"` - Appends to a file. Writing operations, append data at the end of the 
file. The file is created if it does not exist.

`"r+"` - Opens a file to update both reading and writing. The file must exist.

`"w+"` - Creates an empty file for both reading and writing.

`"a+"` - Opens a file for reading and appending.